# How I can create a web service using SQL Server Business Intelligence to create a report and save it as a pdf file on the server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, business-intelligence

I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but I need to create a web service to run report on the server and save it on a pdf file and the send the file name as result. I was wondering if it is possible to create such a service using SQL Server Business Intelligence.
Any thought or recommendation would be appreceiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server reporting services will do this.  It has a web interface and will save reports to various formats including pdf - it can also automatically email the results - all of this can be set up as a schedule or on demand.

Comment: Jimbo, Would you please give me a direction to a sample or document explaining the subject? I'm a newbie and don't know how to start it. thank you.

Comment: reporting services:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx

a good starter book is:
http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-Server%C2%AE-Reporting-Services-Microsoft/dp/0735626472/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1343677886&sr=8-3&keywords=ssrs+reporting+services

The developer version of SQL Server can be picked up for about $50